# Async operations in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe, webforms

ASP.NET Webforms targetting .NET 4.
I need to show a pdf document on a page (in an iframe), loading the pdf takes a lot of time, so the idea is to load the pdf document async and to show a waiting message in the iframe, once the pdf is ready, show the pdf in iframe.

```
// PrintPDFView.aspx
<div id="pdfDiv" style="height: 100%;">
    // show pdf if ready otherwise waiting message
    <iframe runat="server" width="100%" height="100%" id="PDFViewDoc" />
</div>

// PrintPDFView.aspx.cs
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
                //...
                // Long running process
                CallDocumentsService();
                //...
                PDFViewDoc.Attributes["src"] = "ShowPDFView.aspx";
}

// ShowPDFView.aspx
// When the pdf is ready, it will be rendered on this page
<body>
    <div id="LoadingPdf">
        <h1>Loading your document!</h1>    
        <p>This may take a few minutes...</p>
    </div>
</body>

// ShowPDFView.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfToDisplay);
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing you'd probably use JavaScript for rather than a server side technology.

Comment: Your mindset is wrong here. C# Async is not magic. You can't be waiting for something to happen on the server after you've already sent the response. Always keep this in mind -> `Request comes in. Server processes it, generates response, sends response to client, server involvement ends`. To accomplish what you're after, use JavaScript running on the client to load the PDF.

Comment: I'm working on a complicated legacy project, the code that loads the pdf is implemented on server side, making changes at that level is not easy and will break other functionalities

Comment: That's fine, you can do all the PDF serving stuff on the server side, you just need a little JavaScript to detect the state change in the IFRAME.

Comment: So? That doesn't change limitations of how the framework operates. Probably easiest to just show an indeterminate progress bar on the client, and load the PDF via AJAX or iframe. Once it's downloaded, display it and hide the progress bar.

Comment: How about put an UpdatePanel with UpdateProgress (with loading message in format of your choice) in ShowPDFView.aspx.cs?

Comment: You need a Real-Time implementation of codes that combines a Server side code and also a client side code.
The perfect tool for this is SignalR.  This would allow the server side to continue giving your client side updates. You can incorporate a feature like progress counter with such.